# How to show vectors do not span $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

"Given row vectors $v_1,..,v_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $A$ be the $n \times n$ matrix whose columns are given by these vectors. If $\det(A) = 0$, the vectors do not span $\mathbb{R}^n$"

To try and show this, I let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and formed the augmented matrix with $A$ as the LHS and $x$ as the RHS. Since $\det(A)=0$, the unique RREF for $A$ has a row of zeroes. Then, if I can find $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the corresponding entry on the RHS to the row of zeroes on the LHS of the augmented matrix is nonzero, I have that $x$ is not in the span of $v_1,..,v_n$. How do I show that I can always find such an $x$? Or is there a better way of showing the above statement?

Comment: there's a theorem that any n independent vectors span all of R^n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have your square RREF matrix with the row of all $0$s. At that point, place a vector in the augmented column with a $1$ in that row of all $0$s. Then recall that all of the steps used during the row reduction are reversible. Apply their inverses to undo them all. This leaves you withe the original matrix augmented by some vector $x$.

Comment: But how do you know that that entry isn't always 0?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. After you RREF the original un-augmented square matrix, you get to choose whatever vector you want to augment it. You get to _choose_ a vector with a $1$ in the entry that aligns with the row of all $0$s. This is not the vector $x$, it's something you choose. Then you undo all of the row operations that had been used to get the RREF matrix. You end up with _something_ in the augmented column. And this is a vector $x$. By design, if you now RREF $[A|x]$ you will get a row like $[0 \cdots 0 | 1]$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought about it some more and I realised there's nothing to stop you from just placing 1 in that position and working backwards. Apologies, and thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Any row of the RREF of a matrix $A$ is a non-trivial linear combination of the rows of $A$. As you have written $\mathrm{det}(A)=0$, implies a row of the RREF of $A$ is the $\mathbf{0}$ vector. That is a non-trivial linear combination of the rows of $A$ is the $\mathbf{0}$ vector, which implies that the rows of $A$ are not linearly independent.

*Second solution*: We know that the eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots of the equation $p(x)=\mathrm{det}(A-xI)$. We can see that the constant value of this polynomial would be $\mathrm{det}(A)$. Hence $\mathrm{det}(A)=0$, implies that one of the roots of the polynomial is $0$, because the constant term of a polynomial is the product of its roots. Hence $A$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue. Thus there is a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Av=0.v=\mathbf{0}$.